# Passagem por referência

Tags: c, funções

Em um exercício, preciso comparar um determinado número de distâncias e dizer qual ou quais são as menores e imprimi-las. Para isso, eu tenho a seguinte função:

```
void Permuta(FILE *saida, Cidade *C, int *sequencia, int inicio, int termino, int totalViagens, float **distanciasAux)
{
    int i, j;
    totalViagens = TotalViagens(termino);
    if(inicio == termino)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < termino; i++)
            fprintf(saida, "%d\t", sequencia[i]+1);
        fprintf(saida, "= %f\n", Distancia(C, termino, sequencia));

        *distanciasAux = (float *) malloc(totalViagens*sizeof(float));
        float *distancias = *distanciasAux;
        distancias[i] = Distancia(C, termino, sequencia);
        printf("\n%f\n", distancias[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        for(j = inicio; j < termino; j++)
        {
            Troca((sequencia+inicio), (sequencia+j));
            Permuta(saida, C, sequencia, inicio+1, termino, totalViagens, distanciasAux);
            Troca((sequencia+inicio), (sequencia+j));
        }
    }
}
```

Nessa função, eu faço a alocação dinâmica da seguinte maneira, como pode ser visto acima

```
*distanciasAux = (float *) malloc(totalViagens*sizeof(float));
float *distancias = *distanciasAux;
distancias[i] = Distancia(C, termino, sequencia);
printf("\n%f\n", distancias[i]);
```

Na impressão desses resultados, eu tenho os valores corretos das distâncias. Porém, para comparar esses valores, eu preciso fazer em outra função. Essa outra função pode ser vista logo abaixo:

```
void CriaSequencia(FILE *saida, Cidade *C, int *sequencia, int numeroCidade, int totalViagens)
{
    int i;
    totalViagens = TotalViagens(numeroCidade);
    float *distancias;
    for(i = 0; i < numeroCidade; i++)
    {
        sequencia[i] = i;
    }
    Permuta(saida, C, sequencia, 0, numeroCidade, TotalViagens(numeroCidade), &distancias);
    for(i = 0; i < totalViagens; i++)
        printf("\n%f\n", distancias[i]);
}
```

Eu não comecei o processo de comparação pois queria ter certeza de que os valores passados estão corretos. Porém, ao pedir pra imprimir os valores fora da função, tudo o que recebo são valores nulos (0.000000).

Gostaria de saber porquê não está ocorrendo a impressão dos valores corretos e o que pode estar gerando esse problema.

Comment: `sequencia+inicio`. Aqui temos que `sequencia` é um ponteiro e `inicio` é um inteiro. A sua ideia era usar `&sequencia[inicio]`?

Comment: Como é a função `Troca`?